# AdMob ads appears ONLY in emulator

Tags: android, admob, android-virtual-device

I would like to ask about android AdMob advertisements. I have created and finished android application adn then added the Admob Ads. Since then, ads only apear on emulator, but never on my phone(HTC desire s) screen. How is that possible and how to fix it?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/linlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="some text"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:text="some text 2"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/someId1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint1"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal|numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/someId2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint2"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal|numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/someId3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint3"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal|numberSigned" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        googleads:adSize="BANNER"
        googleads:adUnitId="my id" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Part from manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="some.some.some"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.2" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="some.some.some.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And this is java code:

```
package some.some.some;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
double a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, l ,m ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv1.setText("");
            tv2.setText("");
            tv3.setText("");
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
    blowUp.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.info:
        Intent i = new Intent("some.....");
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.preferences:
        Intent p = new Intent("some.......");
        startActivity(p);
        break;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

P.S. My phone is HTC desire s; Android version 2.3.5;
Emulator I am using is 4.2.2

```
05-31 18:31:33.974: I/HtcTextSelection(30023): (sendOnTextChanged)  stopTextSelectionMode
05-31 18:31:33.974: I/HtcTextSelection(30023): (sendOnTextChanged)  stopTextSelectionMode
05-31 18:31:33.994: I/HtcTextSelection(30023): (sendOnTextChanged)  stopTextSelectionMode
05-31 18:31:34.004: I/HtcTextSelection(30023): (sendOnTextChanged)  stopTextSelectionMode
05-31 18:31:34.004: I/HtcTextSelection(30023): (sendOnTextChanged)  stopTextSelectionMode
05-31 18:31:34.004: I/HtcTextSelection(30023): (sendOnTextChanged)  stopTextSelectionMode
05-31 18:31:34.294: D/Database(30023): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.quad.equa/databases/webview.db, flag = 6, file size = 15360
05-31 18:31:34.324: D/Database(30023): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.quad.equa/databases/webview.db, mode: wal, disk free size: 700 M, handle: 0x376840
05-31 18:31:34.364: D/Database(30023): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.quad.equa/databases/webviewCache.db, flag = 6, file size = 6144
05-31 18:31:34.374: I/Database(30023): sqlite returned: error code = 0, msg = Recovered 6 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.quad.equa/databases/webviewCache.db-wal
05-31 18:31:34.374: D/Database(30023): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.quad.equa/databases/webviewCache.db, mode: wal, disk free size: 700 M, handle: 0x3866f0
05-31 18:31:34.394: D/skia(30023): htcFlashPlugin::htcFlashPlugin
05-31 18:31:34.404: D/qct(30023): [RequestQueue.ActivePool.ActivePool] >> Enable Shutdown = true
05-31 18:31:34.404: D/qct(30023): [IdleCache.IdleCache] >> IDLE_CACHE_MAX = 40
05-31 18:31:34.524: D/qct(30023): [WebView.WebView] >> Enable Shutdown = true
05-31 18:31:34.524: D/skia(30023): htcFlashPlugin::htcFlashPlugin
05-31 18:31:34.534: D/qct(30023): [WebView.WebView] >> Enable Shutdown = true
05-31 18:31:34.754: D/dalvikvm(30023): GC_CONCURRENT freed 235K, 42% free 3319K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 11ms+12ms
05-31 18:31:34.854: D/skia(30023): htcFlashPlugin::htcFlashPlugin
05-31 18:31:34.854: E/ActivityThread(30023): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
05-31 18:31:34.864: D/qct(30023): [WebView.WebView] >> Enable Shutdown = true
05-31 18:31:34.864: W/Ads(30023): loadAd called while the ad is already loading, so aborting.
05-31 18:31:34.874: D/ATRecorder(30023): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@40522f48
05-31 18:31:34.874: D/WindowManagerImpl(30023): addView, new view, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40523698
05-31 18:31:34.884: I/Ads(30023): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("9B33F819BBF6446C23116F898BCD7877");
05-31 18:31:34.974: I/HtcTextSelection(30023): (onFocusChanged) focused =true
05-31 18:31:34.984: I/HtcTextSelection(30023): (onFocusChanged) stopTextSelectionMode
05-31 18:31:34.984: I/HtcTextSelection(30023): (onFocusChanged) dismissQuickAction
05-31 18:31:34.984: I/HtcTextSelection(30023): (onFocusChanged) mIsInTextSelectionMode = false
05-31 18:31:35.034: D/dalvikvm(30023): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-2141571499.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
05-31 18:31:35.323: D/dalvikvm(30023): DexOpt: --- END 'ads-2141571499.jar' (success) ---
05-31 18:31:35.323: D/dalvikvm(30023): DEX prep '/data/data/com.quad.equa/cache/ads-2141571499.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 290ms
05-31 18:31:35.573: I/Ads(30023): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"10718683671789989957","u_sd":1.5,"seq_num":"1","slotname":"a15191411a98286","u_w":320,"msid":"com.quad.equa","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","ms":"wJ-iV8c0M8aPxLjIDF2tiuydOAZtgucqOYxrH_rC_il4R8ukh8guYElD8Q6K1aTcVovIgCrTMbs93UHN2CW6WylrvhcItIsZNxBM9MBo6gAHC41ufRI-xrkDBBjl10-m0moCTnRWUlznfnHK3nFPxUGvJ70kE0lCWfZZ7PNLahIqa8o6q6Kf5I8Bktln7v7G2ZXr0pEbeWZjf1XVA8yd0_rUBJmc1Yn8CQ-ke5qm4Kuqchhj-s2_roY9qkNjRjmniZfiPtBkQrfPnbtJbsdQu-P9r3LtXcwgSMP4OnZODWuqu6BvO2o7TqV3GdBKVghaPRgDMhiolK7aMfWNBgG24g","mv":"80210006.com.android.vending","isu":"9B33F819BBF6446C23116F898BCD7877","bas_off":0,"format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"3.android.com.quad.equa","hl":"lt","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":1,"y":573,"x":0,"width":480},"gnt":8,"u_h":533,"pt":1,"carrier":"24602","bas_on":0,"ptime":0,"u_audio":1});</script></head><body></body></html>
05-31 18:31:35.703: D/webkit-timers(30023): [JWebCoreJavaBridge::resume] >> do resume
05-31 18:31:36.303: D/dalvikvm(30023): GC_CONCURRENT freed 266K, 40% free 3539K/5895K, external 0K/0K, paused 4ms+15ms
05-31 18:31:36.673: W/webcore(30023): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
05-31 18:31:36.793: I/Ads(30023): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=10718683671789989957&u_sd=1.5&seq_num=1&u_w=320&msid=com.quad.equa&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&ms=wJ-iV8c0M8aPxLjIDF2tiuydOAZtgucqOYxrH_rC_il4R8ukh8guYElD8Q6K1aTcVovIgCrTMbs93UHN2CW6WylrvhcItIsZNxBM9MBo6gAHC41ufRI-xrkDBBjl10-m0moCTnRWUlznfnHK3nFPxUGvJ70kE0lCWfZZ7PNLahIqa8o6q6Kf5I8Bktln7v7G2ZXr0pEbeWZjf1XVA8yd0_rUBJmc1Yn8CQ-ke5qm4Kuqchhj-s2_roY9qkNjRjmniZfiPtBkQrfPnbtJbsdQu-P9r3LtXcwgSMP4OnZODWuqu6BvO2o7TqV3GdBKVghaPRgDMhiolK7aMfWNBgG24g&mv=80210006.com.android.vending&isu=9B33F819BBF6446C23116F898BCD7877&bas_off=0&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&net=wi&app_name=3.android.com.quad.equa&hl=lt&gnt=8&u_h=533&carrier=24602&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_audio=1&u_so=p&imbf=%40installed_markets%40&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=180&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a15191411a98286&gsb=wi&caps=interactiveVideo_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=48" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
05-31 18:31:36.873: I/Ads(30023): Ad url modified to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=10718683671789989957&u_sd=1.5&seq_num=1&u_w=320&msid=com.quad.equa&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&ms=wJ-iV8c0M8aPxLjIDF2tiuydOAZtgucqOYxrH_rC_il4R8ukh8guYElD8Q6K1aTcVovIgCrTMbs93UHN2CW6WylrvhcItIsZNxBM9MBo6gAHC41ufRI-xrkDBBjl10-m0moCTnRWUlznfnHK3nFPxUGvJ70kE0lCWfZZ7PNLahIqa8o6q6Kf5I8Bktln7v7G2ZXr0pEbeWZjf1XVA8yd0_rUBJmc1Yn8CQ-ke5qm4Kuqchhj-s2_roY9qkNjRjmniZfiPtBkQrfPnbtJbsdQu-P9r3LtXcwgSMP4OnZODWuqu6BvO2o7TqV3GdBKVghaPRgDMhiolK7aMfWNBgG24g&mv=80210006.com.android.vending&isu=9B33F819BBF6446C23116F898BCD7877&bas_off=0&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&net=wi&app_name=3.android.com.quad.equa&hl=lt&gnt=8&u_h=533&carrier=24602&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_audio=1&u_so=p&imbf=8009&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=180&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a15191411a98286&gsb=wi&caps=interactiveVideo_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=48
05-31 18:31:36.873: I/Ads(30023): Request scenario: Online server request.
05-31 18:31:36.963: E/Ads(30023): IOException connecting to ad url.
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023): The following was caught and handled:
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023): java.net.ConnectException: googleads.g.doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:210)
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:440)
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1013)
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:75)
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at com.google.ads.internal.f.b(SourceFile:489)
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at com.google.ads.internal.f.run(SourceFile:460)
05-31 18:31:36.963: I/Ads(30023):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
05-31 18:31:36.963: D/webviewglue(30023): nativeDestroy view: 0x34b118
05-31 18:31:37.172: W/dalvikvm(30023): JNI: DeleteGlobalRef(0xde5b9dc7) failed to find entry (valid=0)
05-31 18:31:37.172: W/dalvikvm(30023): JNI: DeleteGlobalRef(0xde5b9da7) failed to find entry (valid=0)
05-31 18:31:37.172: I/Ads(30023): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
```

Comment: did you remove the addTestDevice line? or just comment it out For eg: adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR); this line

Comment: I did not use anny of test settings at all.

Comment: can you please post your code for admob.

Comment: on which version of emulator you are getting the ads, and not in ur device? if possible pls post manifest and java code.

Answer (score 0):

Add Following Code in the OnCreate Method,it works for me

```
AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
re.setTesting(true);
adview.loadAd(re);
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't help... I Can't undrestand the problem... In the LogCat it sais: OnFailedToReceiveAd(A nettwork error occured.) But I am pretty sure that everything with Internet connection is right...

Comment: Yes it might , have you set the correct googleads:adUnitId="my id" ??

Comment: can you please post you stack trace ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905291/admob-tries-to-connect-at-127-0-0-1-and-fails-always-fires-onfailedtoreceivead  Check this link

Comment: I added what i can see in console

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463376/why-admob-ads-in-any-apps-not-displaying.  i think your host is changed

Answer (score 0):

After your setContentView line add this code

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.ad);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

and check it on your device.

Comment: This also does not help, LogCat still say: OnFailedToReceiveAd(A nettwork error occured.)